# Not able to deploy database on App Harbor

Tags: database, deployment, appharbor

I am trying to deploy an instance which is getting the following build error on App Harbor

```
Build FAILED.

"D:\temp\gcp22bmp.ggi\input\src\ShareBill.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"D:\temp\gcp22bmp.ggi\input\src\Sharebill.Database\Sharebill.Database.dbproj" (default target) (5) ->
  D:\temp\gcp22bmp.ggi\input\src\packages\TeamData\Microsoft.Data.Schema.SqlTasks.targets(5,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\TeamData\Microsoft.Data.Schema.TSqlTasks.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk. [D:\temp\gcp22bmp.ggi\input\src\Sharebill.Database\Sharebill.Database.dbproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

I know this is because the sql targets that are generally present here - C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\TeamData

are not present on the deployment server.

What should I do to deploy the data base now? Is there any other way to deploy the database. I have not used code first in EF, but I still want to have db migrations automatically applied.

I am assuming that if i get the db project running it would automatically find the schema differences and apply the changes to the database.

Comment: I haven't used the database projects, but if you're already using Entity Framework, this approach might be better: http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/04/24/automatic-migrations-with-entity-framework-4-3

Comment: thanks, I have gone through this doc already. I wonder if it would apply to me as well since I am using the Model first approach in EF as opposed to the code first approach.

Answer (score 0):

I host a project on AppHarbor and use [FluentMigrator](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator) to deploy my database changes.

It is really easy to implement, just follow the [documentation](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki) you can use their fluent interface or even just use it to execute sql.

As an example I run the following from my Application_Start of my Global.asax.cs - just put  you migrations in the same assembly as the NOP MigrationMarker class:

```
        const string connectionString = @"Data Source=localhost, 1433;Initial Catalog=testdb;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
        Announcer announcer = new TextWriterAnnouncer(s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s));
        announcer.ShowSql = true;

        var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MigrationMarker));
        var migrationContext = new RunnerContext(announcer);

        var options = new ProcessorOptions
                          {
                              PreviewOnly = false, // set to true to see the SQL
                              Timeout = 60
                          };

        var factory = new SqlServer2008ProcessorFactory();
        var processor = factory.Create(connectionString, announcer, options);
        var runner = new MigrationRunner(assembly, migrationContext, processor);

        runner.MigrateUp(true);
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this applies to the question asked.